# Python/Pandas: groupby / find specific row / drop all rows below

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a dataframe - and I want to drop specific rows per group ("id"):

```
id - month - max 
1 - 112016 - 41
1 - 012017 - 46
1 - 022017 - 156
1 - 032017 - 164
1 - 042017 - 51
2 - 042017 - 26
2 - 052017 - 156
2 - 062017 - 17
```

- for each "id", find location of first row (sorted by "month") where "max" is >62
- keep all rows above (within this group), drop rest of rows

Expected result:

```
id - month - max 
1 - 112016 - 41
1 - 012017 - 46
2 - 042017 - 26
```

I'm able to identify the first row which has to be deleted per group, but I'm stuck from that point on:

```
df[df.max > 62].sort_values(['month'], ascending=[True]).groupby('id', as_index=False).first()
```

How can I get rid of the rows?

Best regards,
david

Comment: So output is correct?

Comment: Do you need also first value of group `>62` in output?

Comment: @Dan: You are right, that was an error. I edited it - thank you very much!

Comment: @jezrael: only if is the first value within this group - otherwise not!

Comment: @workah0lic - so use my first solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#convert to datetimes
df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['month'], format='%m%Y')
#sorting per groups if necessary
df = df.sort_values(['id','month'])
#comopare by gt (>) for cumulative sum per groups and filter equal 0
df1= df[df['max'].gt(62).groupby(df['id']).cumsum().eq(0)]
print (df1)

   id      month  max
0   1 2016-11-01   41
1   1 2017-01-01   46
```

Or use a custom function if need also first value `>62`:

```
#convert to datetimes
df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['month'], format='%m%Y')
#sorting per groups if necessary
df = df.sort_values(['id','month'])

def f(x):
    m = x['max'].gt(62)
    first = m[m].index[0]
    x = x.loc[ :first]
    return x

df = df.groupby('id', group_keys=False).apply(f)
print (df)

   id      month  max
0   1 2016-11-01   41
1   1 2017-01-01   46
2   1 2017-02-01  156
5   2 2017-04-01   83
```

Comment: Thank you very much! First version works perfectly :) best regards!

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
datadict = {
        'id': [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2],
        'max': [41,46,156,164,51,83,156,17],
        'month': ['112016', '012017', '022017', '032017', '042017', '042017', '052017', '062017'],
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(datadict)
print (df)
   id  max   month
0   1   41  112016
1   1   46  012017
2   1  156  022017
3   1  164  032017
4   1   51  042017
5   2   83  042017
6   2  156  052017
7   2   17  062017

df = df.loc[df['max']>62,:]
print (df)
   id  max   month
2   1  156  022017
3   1  164  032017
5   2   83  042017
6   2  156  052017
```